# How can I change "flat 3 245a HILL road" to "Flat 3 245A Hill Road" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When someone enters a street address into a single field on a form, I want to convert the street address to something like Title Case. It isn't quite Title Case as a letter that comes directly after a string of numbers should be upper case.

As an example I want "Flat 3 245A Hill Road" not "Flat 3 245a Hill Road".

I know that:

```
var str = "flat 3 245 HILL road";
str.split(" ").map(function(i){return i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substring(1).to LowerCase()}).join(" ");
```

will convert "flat 3 245a HILL road" to "Flat 3 245a Hill Road".

but I want it to convert to "Flat 3 245A Hill Road"?

Another example

It should be "18B Hill Crescent" not "18b Hill Crescent"

Comment: is this the only string you need to convert, or are there more, such that you can describe the pattern they follow? (in which case a regex [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a replacement handling function that knows about groups will be a quite workable solution)

Comment: If there is no standardized format for the string, it will be hard to formulate a general solution for it.

Comment: if you are getting each address input value separately, then you can capitalize just the unit number/letter field.... like Address, Apt., City, State, Postal Code.... then you can just add capitalization to the Apt. field. Otherwise, this would be very difficult to pinpoint just the unit number/letter.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans They don't always follow the same pattern, but always I want all words the start with a letter to be Title case and any letter that comes immediately after a number to be uppercase.

Comment: @JoAnne can you add that fact to your question, and show some examples so that everyone can help out with getting you the correct pattern replacement?

Comment: @Liquidchrome  The street address is just one field.  City, state, postcode are different fields so I don't have toworry about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
str.replace(/(\d+)([a-z]+)/, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); })
```

to handle the 245a

Comment: I am rather new to javascript - this is the first thing I have tried to do.  How would I combine your suggestion with the code in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Based on "I want all words the start with a letter to be Title case and any letter that comes immediately after a number to be uppercase", this sounds like a job for regex:

```
// words (possibly surrounded by numbers, spaces, etc)
var re = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;

// replace those such that they start uppercase
var replaced = yourstring.replace(re, function(matchedLetters) {
  return matchedLetters.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +
         matchedLetters.substring(1).toLowerCase();
});
```

This will give you `Flat 3 245A Hill Road`, `18B Hill Crescent`. etc. without having to care about what's in the string: any stretch of continuous text will get converted to uppercase first letter, lowercase remainder.

Comment: Will this work if the person inputs  18b hill crescent?

Comment: even though the anwer could have been "yes", the real answer is "don't ask, try it and find out, and if it doesn't work, comment on the fact that it doesn't work" =)

Comment: True, sorry for asking before thinking.

Comment: This works well, but I don't have the skills to fit into the rest of the code properly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure the situation is more general, so one approach can be preparing an array of all the words you want capitalized, so you can extend it later.

```
var str = "flat 3 245 HILL road",
    wordsToCapitalize = ['road', 'hill', 'flat'],
    pattern;

wordsToCapitalize.forEach(function(word) {
    pattern = new RegExp('(' + word + ')', 'gi');
    str = str.replace(pattern, (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
            + word.slice(1)));
});
```

What is happening above is you are searching for a string, regardless the capitalization, in your original string. Each time you prepare a global RegExp pattern, based on which you replace the word with one capitalized.

Note how, because of the case-insensitivity of the search, you do the char manipulation on all-lowercase word.

Comment: There is no reason to have a "list of known words" though, you can just indiscriminantly replace any [a-zA-Z]+ range. With this list approach, for instance, OPs original string will fail to properly convert (`245a` won't turn into `245A`)

Comment: Ok, I missed the "a" case, I'll edit. About the list - I think, when it comes to addresses, it is justified.

Comment: it'd be an impossible to maintain list, though. There's a lot of addresses even in just the US.

Comment: We have over 250,000 different street names in our database, so maintaining a list is not practical.